# jquery getcontext on dynamic id canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, canvas

I am a newbie on jQuery and JavaScript. I'm trying to create an dynamic id for a canvas, and then get its context, this is the code

```
$.fn.wm= function(cfg){
var doc = this,
gcanvas = {},
gctx = {},
imgQueue = [],
className = "wm-mid",
wm = false,
wmPosition = "center",
wmPath = "wm.png?"+(+(new Date())),
opacity = (255/(100/50)), // 50%
idcanvas =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), 
  initCanvas = function(){
  gcanvas = $('<canvas id="' + idcanvas +'"  style="display:none;" > </canvas>');
  idcanvas = "#" + idcanvas;
  $('body').append(gcanvas);
  gctx = $('"'+ idcanvas +'"').getContext("2d");
    },
initWm = function(){
        wm = $('<img src="'+wmPath+'" />');
        ......
```

but I'm getting this error when try to add the canvas at the body:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#C72" throw new Error(
>   "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

is it possible to do what I'm trying to do??

**Edit:**

I found the error, in this line change

```
gctx = $('"'+ idcanvas +'"').getContext("2d");
```

for this

```
gctx = $('#'+ idcanvas ).get(0).getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have created the *canvas* element but in memory not the part of html yet. To do that you need to append the *canvas* to your body.
Just add the below code after you have created the *canvas* element and it will work fine.

`$("body").append(gcanvas);`

Comment: thanks, idone, now the error appears when try to get the context